# How to require a Dropdown that has a value no longer in the Dropdown Options?

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I'm using Angular 6 and have a required `<select>` element with the current options of `a, b, c`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="mySelect" [(ngModel)]="vm.mySelect" #mySelect="ngModel" required>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

However, lets say `d` was a valid option previously and is what is saved to my back-end database. So when I load my page, I'm setting `mySelect` to what is stored in the database and if I inspect `mySelect` with Chrome devtools, it has a  `ng-relfect-model="d"` but the select element is empty because `d` isn't an option anymore.

When I check my `NgForm`'s `.valid` property, I would expect it to return `false`. However, it returns `true`.

How can make it so my select element is invalid if it has a value that is not a valid option?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, and `c` static values?

Comment: @lealceldeiro no, usually I will have option values coming from `*ngFor` : `<option *ngFor="let option of vm.options" [value]="option.value">{{option.description}}</option>`

Comment: you should add that to the question because it is relevant.

Comment: I'd check, when loading the info from database, if the old (saved in database) value is a valid one now, and if not, select by default a new value (or whatever you decide to do), instead of applying additional checkings and so on (that will be useful just the first time, since after that the values will always be valid)

Comment: @lealceldeiro what do you mean by "select by default a new value"?

Comment: Suppose we have in `vm.options` values `a`,`b`,`c` and from database is coming `d`.... instead of placing a validation in the html I'd rather make a decision right away in the _ts_ code. If I know the valid values are `a`,`b`,`c` and the old is `d` I choose `a` to be selected (because `d` is not in the list and `a` is the first one) (you must adapt this to your logic). Basically, that's the idea. If you update the post and put the logic of retrieving the value from DB and the desired behavior (what to do when the database values is not in `vm.options`) I can post a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be add `pattern="['a' | 'b' | 'c']"` to your select:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        name="mySelect" 
        [(ngModel)]="vm.mySelect" 
        #mySelect="ngModel" 
        pattern="['a' | 'b' | 'c']"
        required>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

or, if you have an array of options, you could construct a pattern in your ts file and pass it to HTML.

ts file:

```
pattern = new RegExp(['a','b', 'c'].join('|'));
```

HTML file:

```
<select [patern]="patern"...>...
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2fueud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (enter invalid value in the input box)

**NEW UPDATE**

In case of `vm.options` as array of objects having `value` property try following:

in your ts file:

```
vm = {
  options: [
    { 
      description: 'a1', 
      value: 'a' 
    }, 
    { 
      description: 'b1', 
      value: 'b' 
    }, 
    { 
      description: 'c1', 
      value: 'c' 
    }
  ],
  mySelect: null
};
pattern = new RegExp('^[' + this.vm.options.map(o => o.value).join('') + ']$');
```

in your HTML file:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        name="mySelect" 
        [(ngModel)]="vm.mySelect" 
        #mySelect="ngModel" 
        required 
        [pattern]="pattern">
  <option *ngFor="let option of vm.options" 
          [value]="option.value">{{option.description}}</option>
</select>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2fueud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is updated as well

Comment: My example above was with static options for simplicity, but usually I will have option values coming from `*ngFor` : `<option *ngFor="let option of vm.options" [value]="option.value">{{option.description}}</option>`

Comment: please see my updated answer. Use `pattern = new RegExp(vm.options.map(option => option.value).join('|'));`

Comment: @RyanBuening I rather would check, when loading the info from database, if the old (saved in database) value is a valid one now, and if not, select by default a new value (or whatever you decide to do), instead of applying additional checkings and so on (that will be useful just the first time, since after that the values will always be valid)

Comment: @Andriy my options are an array of objects `myObject[]`: `[{ "description": "a1", "value": "a"}, { "description": "b1", "value": "b"}]`

My pattern validator keeps returning false with the following: `pattern="new RegExp(vm?.myObject.map(object => object.value).join('|'))"`

Comment: @lealceldeiro thanks for the comment, I'll explore that as well.

Comment: @RyanBuening, new RegExp should be set at your ts file and passed to your HTML via [patern]="your-pattern". I will update my stack blitz with your array of objects

Comment: @RyanBuening, please see my new update at the answer and updated stackblitz